# Compare Post Method Valve to array value

Tags: php, arrays, post, methods, compare

Im trying to compare values from forms received by `post method` to array values which is two dimenstional, im trying to use `in_array` method but it incrementation the mistake variable and im sure about the value from input and value from array are the same
`$i` is counter od for loop

```
     $answer = array(array(1,3)) 
     // `1` is the number
     // `2` is the Valur od correct answer                           
     For($i=0;$i<25;$i++) {
       if(in_array($_POST['p'.$i], $answers[$i][0])) {
         $points++;
       } else { 
         $Mistakes++;
       }
     }
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="radio" name="p1" value="3"/>answer
```

Comment: a bit more info about your data?

Comment: perhaps what youre tryign to do is this in_array($_POST['p'.$i], $answers[$i])  ... not too sure since i dont know how your data is represented

Comment: its worth noting that you seem to be ignoring the 0th element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually just work with the notion there could be fewer or more questions

```
$answers['p1'] = 3; 
$answers['p2'] = 1;

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){

    if (preg_match('/p[0-9]{1,}/', $key)){

        $question = $key;
        $answer = $value;

        if ($answer == $answers[$question]){
            $points++;
        } else {
            $Mistakes++;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I Havel tried this but still its couting mistake variable in the else clause

Comment: you realize that if a radio is not selected then there will be nothing in $_POST for that question?  which means you should also have some method to take into account those "mistakes" ?  unless of course simply ignoring a question isnt actually a mistake

Comment: are you sure you are POSTing the data?  maybe something wrong with your radio button definitions?

Comment: Okay i have made a stupid mistake in HTML now ypur solution working perfectly. Thank You.